# Handling MVC action result using JQuery post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am calling MVC action something like below:

```
var RestaurantDetailsUIforForeignWidget = {
    frmId: '',
    onFormSubmit: function () {
        var frm = $(RestaurantDetailsUIforForeignWidget.frmId);
        var divResult;
        $('.offerbox').hide();
        $.post(frm.attr('action'), frm.serialize(), function (html) {
            // $('#section-time-slots').html(html)
            $('#contentAll').html(html);
            DisplayOffer();
        });
        return false;
    },
    updateTimeDesc: function () {
        $('#time').val($('#SittingTime option:selected').html());
    },
    init: function (frmId) {
        RestaurantDetailsUIforForeignWidget.frmId = frmId;
        $('#SittingTime').bind('change', RestaurantDetailsUIforForeignWidget.updateTimeDesc);
        $(frmId).bind('submit', RestaurantDetailsUIforForeignWidget.onFormSubmit);
        RestaurantDetailsUIforForeignWidget.updateTimeDesc();
    }
};
```

As you can see `$('#contentAll').html(html);` updates whole view content with the result. What I want is to get a single div from html output and update the `$('#section-time-slots')` instead.

Please help me guys... thanks :)

Comment: Does the server have to return the full view, cant it return only the section that you want so that you can update your $('#section-time-slots')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $.post(frm.attr('action'), frm.serialize(), function (html) {
        $('#section-time-slots').html($("#IdOfRequiredElementInResponse", html).html());
        DisplayOffer();
    });
```